# returning a radio button value to another window in WPF to use as variable

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Im trying to create a dodge game, in the said game i created a settings window in which i would like the user to decide whether he want to have bombs in the playboard or not and decide on the difficulty level using radio buttons. then i would like to take the "answer" from the choosed radio buttons and turn them into variables which will control the game:
for example. if bombs are enabled radio button is checked i would like to ask my gamewindow to create bombs on the board and vice versa.
same goes for the difficulty radio buttons

```
public GameWindow()
    {
        
        GameB = new Board(boardsize, 3, true );
        VillianSpirit = new Image[GameB.NumberofVillians];
        bombs = new Image[GameB.BombCount];
```

}

as you can see im creating a board (from class board i already have which contructs a board accoring to 3 paramters - boardsize, difficulty (which i set to 3 just to check its working) and bool which says if bombs are enabled (set true just to check its working).

now i cant figure out how to make my settings window send a bool or int to use as variables to create the GameB (game board)
here is the settings window code

```
<Window x:Class="rotket.SettingsWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rotket"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="SettingsWindow" Height="200" Width="400">

<Grid x:Name="SettingsButtons" Height="400" Width="400">
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" x:Name="YesBombs" Content="Yes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="YesBombs_Checked" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="No" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Do you want to have bombs enabled?" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Width="120"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Description2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,6,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Which difficulty would you like to play?" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group2" x:Name="EasyD" Content="Easy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group2" x:Name="NormalD" Content="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group2" x:Name="BrutalD" Content="Brutal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.459,0.168" />
    <Button x:Name="ExitSettings" Content="Exit To Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Click="ExitSettings_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

here is cs code

```
 public partial class SettingsWindow : Window
{
    public SettingsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }    

    private void ExitSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void YesBombs_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var YesBombs = sender as RadioButton;
        YesBombs.IsChecked = 
        
    }
}
```

}

i couldn't figure it out past this, if anyone can help, i will really appreciate it

Comment: Take a look at the MVVM architectural pattern. Transfer data between windows by making them use the same view model instance.

Comment: can you please redirect me to a good source? i cant find any

Answer (score -1):

You can add a settings file to your project with a bool setting that will be your radio button value, then you can read that setting when creating the game window.

Comment: and how would i create a settings file? can you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: @Yu1208 Transferring data inside a single application via writing and reading a file is nonsense.